# How to start EC2 instance in cluster with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ecs

I would like to start a task definition on an instance within my cluster (not in the default one). So something like:

1. create a cluster
2. create a task definition with a docker image (I have a docker image
   already pushed to ecs)
3. run the task definition in the cluster
4. I would like to add a keypair to the ec2 instance for ssh access

I have tried to use these functions form boto3 (ec2, ecs)

- create_cluster
- run_task
- register_container_instance
- register_task_definition
- run_instances

I managed to run an instance with [run_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances), it works perfectly well but I want to run an instance in my cluster. Here is my code:

```
    def run_instances():
        response = ec2.run_instances(
            BlockDeviceMappings=[
            {
                'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
                'Ebs': {
                     'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                     'VolumeSize': 8,
                     'VolumeType': 'gp2'
                },
            },
        ],
        ImageId='ami-06df494fbd695b854',
        InstanceType='m3.medium',
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        Monitoring={
            'Enabled': False
        })
        return response
```

There is a running instance on ec2 console but it doesn't appear in any of the clusters in the ecs console (I tried it with an ecs-optimized ami and with a regular one).

I also tried to follow these steps for getting my system up and running in a cluster without success:
https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_ecs/test_ecs_boto3.py

Could you please help me find out what do I miss? Is there ant other setup have to make beside calling these SDK functions?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you looking for? Ec2 or ECS? - to start ec2 instance use [run_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances)

Comment: I managed to run instance with [run_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances), it works perfectly well but I want to run an instance in my cluster. Please see my updated question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run an instance that uses `ECS Optimized AMI` since those AMIs have ECS agent preinstalled on them otherwise you would need to install ECS agent yourself and bake a custom AMI.

By default, your ECS optimized instance launches into your default cluster, but you can specify alternative cluster name in `UserData` property of `run_instances` function

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=your_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

The list of available ECS AMIs is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html)

Comment: Awsome. Works like a charm. One note: I had to attach a role with AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role policy to the running instance as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523282/aws-ecs-error-when-running-task-no-container-instances-were-found-in-your-clust/38035652). Here is how to do it: [CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/)
[aws console](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/)