# Security group egress rule to only permit ECR requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecr

When using ECR to store container images for use with ECS, the EC2 instance (or Fargate service) must have a security group that permits access (over the public internet) to the account-specific repository URI.

Many organisations have strict IP whitelisting rules, which generally doesn't permit enabling outbound port 443 for all IPs.

There's no VPC endpoint interface/gateway available for ECR, and presumably like most AWS services, its IP address is elastic and could change at any point.

So how an you add an egress rule to a security group that permits outbound access over port 443 to an ECR URI, without opening it up to all IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the IP address of the endpoint could change, it would only change to another IP address in a fairly large CIDR block. Amazon publish all of their IP address ranges in a .json file obtainable here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ip-ranges-json/

You could narrow it down to the IP address range for the EC2 and AMAZON services in the region which you deploy to. Albeit the range is fairly large.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to write a lambda that will periodically update the SG on the fly based on those ranges. Not perfect, but it's better than completely opening up the port.

Comment: There are ~370 IP ranges for EC2 / AMAZON services (per region)... and security group has limit of 60 rules.... so how did you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS PrivateLink to achieve this; see [Amazon ECR interface VPC endpoints (AWS PrivateLink)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html).

Answer (score -6):

Open 
 `DNS (UDP) 53 for 0.0.0.0/0` and `HTTPS 443 for 0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: Thank you, but that would open all traffic on ports 53 and 443, which is against our security policy.

Comment: I would suggest following to "least privilege" principle e.g. don't open your component worldwide - open it to the known components only.