# AWS: ecs run task with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I run the command to run my ecs task:

**aws ecs run-task  --cluster tryimport --task-definition fromecr --network-configuration { security_groups: ["sg-e9bh4ab9"], subnets: ["subnet-0b170efc0b8f6f53b"]}

zsh: parse error near `}'**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put the config e.g. in single quotes.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @luk3202, i corrected.

But as well, i had to specify the launch-type="FARGATE", see also:
[AWS ECS Error when running task: No Container Instances were found in your cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523282/aws-ecs-error-when-running-task-no-container-instances-were-found-in-your-clust)

and also {"assignPublicIp": "ENABLED" ...

Thus in my example the solution is:

```
aws ecs run-task  --cluster tryimport --task-definition fromecr:2 --launch-type="FARGATE" --network-configuration '{ "awsvpcConfiguration": { "assignPublicIp":"ENABLED", "securityGroups": ["sg-e9bd4ab9"], "subnets": ["subnet-0b170efc0b8f6f53b"]}}'
```

Comment: There is a small typo after ENABLED in the sample : its missing a " character.
If you can correct that :)